# Why is the mod prime p used in Secure Multi-Party Computation (implementing Shamir Secret Sharing) much larger than the sum of shares (secret)

Tags: encryption, cryptography

While learning about cryptography in class, our lecturer gave us a sample code to run. I understand the gist of how Shamir Secret Sharing and Secure Multi-Party Computing (SMPC) work, but what I fail to understand is why the modular prime p we select has to be very much larger than the secret information we are dealing with.

Due to certain reasons, I am not allowed to post the sample code our lecturer wrote but I'll explain the algorithm of the code.

Encryption Algorithm:

```
    1. Secret S is defined whereby S = x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_n, whereby each x term is within the field of 
       p (1 <= x <= p-1) and n is the total number of parties (P_1, P_2, ..., P_n) involved.
    2. Each party has a specific polynomial used to calculate its share. 
       f_1(x) = x_1 + a_(1,1)(x) + a_(1,2)(x)^2 +...+ a_(1, (k-1))(x)^(k-1),
       f_2(x) = x_2 + a_(2,1)(x) + a_(2,2)(x)^2 +...+ a_(2, (k-1))(x)^(k-1), ...
       f_n(x) = x_n + a_(n,1)(x) + a_(n,2)(x)^2 +...+ a_(n, (k-1))(x)^(k-1).
    3. for i = 1 to n by +1 do
    4. for j = 1 to n by +1 do
    5. Calculate u_(i,j) = f_i(j)
    6. end for j
    7. end for i
    8. for i = 1 to n by +1 do
    9. for j = 1 to n by +1 do 
    10. v[i][0] = i
    11. Calculate share[i][1] = (u[1][i] + u[2][i] +...+ u[n][i])
    12. end for j
    13. end for i
```

For the decryption of the secret, we used Shamir's Secret Sharing method where k number of shares are chosen and the Lagrange polynomial calculated for the chosen shares, f(x) = λ_1(share[1]) + λ_2(share[2]) +...+ λ_k(share[k]).

In my lecturer's example, they used secret, s = 80, and modular prime p = 1009. In Shamir's Secret Sharing, the modular prime p was always only slightly larger for the encryption and decryption to work correctly but in SMPC, the p is more than 10 times the secret, any smaller and the secret could not be decrypted. Can someone explain why?

Manual calculation of shares:
[image]

share_1 = (1, 208), share_2 = (2, 83), share_3 = (3, 208), share_4 = (4, 965), share_5 = (5, 597), share_6 = (6, 253), share_7 = (7, 961)

Comment: The secret must be less than the prime, so the prime would need to be at least 128 bits, preferably 256.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I see. But how come in Shamir Secret Sharing, a prime slightly larger than the secret (i.e. secret = 80, prime p = 81) is acceptable but in secure multi-party computing it isn't (i.e. secret = 80, prime p = 1009, as in my example above)?
What's the difference between the two that the requirement of the prime p used has to differ so much?

Comment: A prime slightly larger than a small secret is not acceptable. In any case, large prime or not, if the attacker knows the secret is small than he can easily guess it. So smallness is a weakness of the secret that cannot be cured by using a larger prime. However, using a prime only slightly larger than a small secret confirms that the secret is small. Just like in symmetric key cryptography a secret needs to have at least 128 bits of entropy to be considered secure, and the prime must be at least that large. Of course toy problems may use smaller values for illustrative purposes.